# Modulus Function issue.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, soft-question

> I'm asked to solve $$|x+1|>x^2-5$$

My attempt,

For  my basic inequality skill, this is a very easy question.

Since $$|x|=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x, x \geq0 & \\ 
 -x,x<0& 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then for $x<-1$

$x^2+x-4<0$

$\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}<x<\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$

Then for $x\geq-1$

$x+1 >x^2-5$

$x^2-x-6 <0$

$-2 < x<3$

So combine the ranges,

I got $\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}<x<3$

So, a senior told me that basically my solution is correct, but instead of $x< -1$, I should write $x \leq -1$. Why? According to the definition of modulus function which shows that I'm correct. But why he said that actually the = sign can be for both. So, he asked me don't be bothered too much by this trivial issue. I really don't understand why he said so. Can anyone explain it for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution looks good.

Comment: The final result is correct but the intermediate step $x+1 \geq x^2-5$ is wrong.

Comment: Just a typo for it. Fixed ! @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2):

The senior person is both right and wrong. Right because $|x|=-x$ is indeed true for $x\le0$, but wrong because the case of $x=0$ is already handled (by $x\ge0$) and needn't be repeated.

---

The discussion can be made as follows:

- $x+1\ge0\to x+1>x^2-5\to-2<x<3\to-1\le x<3$,
- $x+1<0\to -(x+1)>x^2-5\to-\dfrac{\sqrt{17}+1}2<x<\dfrac{\sqrt{17}-1}2\to-\dfrac{\sqrt{17}+1}2<x<-1$

This is essentially what you did.

Comment: Can you give me more example of a statement in math, which right and wrong simultaneously? The solution of Mathxx is right and  the senior must  be shut up.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg "the senior must be shut up": why ??

Comment: Because the solution of Mathxx is right. What does he want else?

Answer (score 0):

It's $x+1>x^2-5$ or $x+1<-x^2+5$  without any additional cases.

because if $x^2-5<0$ then the inequality is obviously true.

We get $-2<x<3$ or $\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}<x<\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$, which gives your answer:
$$\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}<x<3$$
I think your solution is right, but your way is bad.

For example, solve the following inequality:
$$|x^3+x-1|>2-x$$

By your way we need to solve two inequalities: $x^3+x-1\geq0$ and $x^3+x-1<0$.

I don't say that it's hard (sometimes it's just impossible!), I say that it's not necessary.

Indeed, $|x|>a\Leftrightarrow x>a$ or $x<-a$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$

because for $a<0$ the inequality $|x|>a$ is obvious.

Thus, $|x^3+x-1|>2-x$ gives $x^3+x-1>2-x$ or $x^3+x-1<-2+x$,

which is $x^3+2x-3>0$ or $x^3+1<0$, which is

$x^3-x^2+x^2-x+3x-3>0$ or $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)<0$, which is

$(x-1)(x^2+x+3)>0$ or $x<-1$, which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$$

Comment: This recasting has a variable expression on the right side which might be positive or negative depending on $x.$

Comment: @coffeemath I explained this point for you. See now, please.

Comment: Very confuse explanation.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I fixed my post for you and explained, what I mean. See now, please.

Comment: I can't decifer "without any cases else", I don't know what "the inequality" refer to, and the obviousness is not obvious to me.

Comment: @Yves Daoust My statement is: For all $a\in \mathbb R$ we have: $|x|>a\Leftrightarrow$ $x<-a$ or $x>a$.

Comment: Is "without any cases else" English ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59800/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @Yves Daoust Without the case $x<-1$ and without the case $x\geq-1$. Maybe it's English because my English is very bad. If you understood what I mean to say, fix my post please. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I didn't.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I fixed my post. I changed "else" with " additional ". See now, please.

Comment: Second sentence still completely opaque.

Comment: @Yves Daoust If $x^2-5<0$ then $|x+1|>x^2-5$ is obviously true.

Comment: In what way does this help, it is nowhere used ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I gave a full explaining of my reasoning. See now, please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: incredible ! You completely not addressed my remark, and added loads of irrelevant material. Bye.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Bye Bye!